# Dynamic Services URL property for Android

Tags: android, smart-device, genexus

My App has the "Dynamic Services URL" set to true.
This is because we have several Application Servers and, also, the URL might change depending on the network we are connected to.

Android:
The App gets a menu on the AppBar (upper-right corner) with a "Settings" option in it.
The App startup invokes an Authentication procedure, that requires access to the Application Server.

**Q1:** If the last Application Server is unavailable (eg, device connected to a different network) the App will return a "Error: Connect time out" and will not give the Settings Menu, not allowing me to change the URL.
Even if i go to the device settings and Clear the app data, still, the app will try to reconect to the last / default Services URL.
It seems impossible to use the App again, until the previous Application Server becomes available so I can have access to the Settings Menu.
Is there any other way to change the Service URL?

[image: Q1]

**Q2:** I will have to create my own "settings" screen for the App (where user can select a default theme, default nº of rows, etc).
Can I add a new option into the menu that genexus creates (so I don't have 2 Settings menus)?

[image: Q2]

Answer (score 0):

The fist point is officially recognized as a bug. See [this SAC](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,36545)

The second point: I have no clue on how to achieve that (unify the 2 settings screens or create a custom edit box for setting the dynamic services URL). If there is a way, it may be programming an external object.